# maven-android-plugin failed always on aapt not found

Tags: maven, aapt, android-maven-plugin

```
 [INFO] /bin/sh: /opt/tools/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/aapt: not found
    [ERROR] Error when generating sources.
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: 
        at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.generateR(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:338)
        at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.execute(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:102)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    Caused by: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.ExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = /bin/sh -c cd /home/bo/ws/jayway-maven-android-plugin-samples-81169dd/helloflashlight && /opt/tools/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/aapt package -m -J /home/bo/ws/jayway-maven-android-plugin-samples-81169dd/helloflashlight/target/generated-sources/r -M /home/bo/ws/jayway-maven-android-plugin-samples-81169dd/helloflashlight/AndroidManifest.xml -S /home/bo/ws/jayway-maven-android-plugin-samples-81169dd/helloflashlight/res --auto-add-overlay -I /opt/tools/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-7/android.jar, Result = 127
```

Comment: Is this the correct path ? Ie does the `/opt/tools/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/aapt` path exists ?

Answer (score 1):

Known issue with the latest version:

http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20OpSys%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=253

Also duplicated for 252 and 251. I'm having the same problem.

Comment: my bad, i should have put the tools and platform-tools into PATH